# Upload image google cloud storage error IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-client

This my code to upload image to google cloud storage with google client api

```
_serviceStorage= [GTLServiceStorage new];
_serviceStorage.APIKey = GoogleAPI ;
NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"StorageSample: Google Cloud Storage";
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *oAuthVC = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
      initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeStorageDevstorageReadWrite
           clientID:GoogleClientID
       clientSecret:GoogleClientSecret
   keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
  completionHandler:^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {

  NSString * _accessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [auth.parameters objectForKey:@"access_token"]];

  _serviceStorage.additionalHTTPHeaders = @{@"x-goog-project-id": GoogleProjectID, @"Content-Type": @"application/json-rpc", @"Accept": @"application/json-rpc", @"Authorization": _accessToken};

  _serviceStorage.authorizer = auth;
  _serviceStorage.retryEnabled = YES;


  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  });
}];


UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-user-default.png"];
NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParam = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
GTLStorageObject *storageObj = [GTLStorageObject object];
storageObj.name = @"cc.png";

GTLQueryStorage *query = [GTLQueryStorage queryForObjectsInsertWithObject:storageObj bucket:@"my-test-app" uploadParameters:uploadParam];
GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [_serviceStorage executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
NSLog(@"%@",error.debugDescription);
}
}];

ticket.uploadProgressBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
 unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead,
 unsigned long long dataLength) {
//self.progressView.progress = (float)numberOfBytesRead/(float)dataLength;
};
```

It' alway show error

> 2015-10-14 12:41:44.399 Pix[21848:145791] Error
>   Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "(Login Required)"
>   UserInfo={error=Login Required, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject
>   0x7b88d7e0: {message:"Login Required" code:401 data:[1]},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Login Required)}

How i fix it?

Comment: As error states: user is not logined. Check if user if login or not. If not, then present google sign in view.

Comment: I use cloud storage to upload image so client don't need login

Comment: But according to your error, the user must login before uploading images. Actually for GTLServiceTicket to execute, it need a loginId type parameter which it doesn't have currently.

Comment: Flow post in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343889/upload-google-cloud-storage-ios?rq=1 , but error alway show . Can you help me about example code